# Nested enums in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I want to define some enums for the various ajax services that I have available in my web application, like:

```
Enum Service
{
    REGISTER,
    LOGIN,
    NEWS,
    FAQ
}
```

However, each of these enums will also have a certain state like Failed, Loaded, etc. So I want to be able to use `REGISTER.LOADED`, `LOGIN.LOADED` etc, to fire up events on my event bus. However each state enum must be unique. I.e `Register.LOADED` must be different from `FAQ.LOADED`, and so on.

Edit: Also, I must be able to store all states in the same hashmap, e.g `Register.LOADED` and `Login.LOADED` must be storable in the same hashmap. And the parent service enums, i.e`LOGIN, REGISTER` etc must be storable in the same hashmap as well.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there were some good answers which may work well for other situations, I've decided to go with the following solution as it works best for my situation:

```
public enum Service
{
    LOGIN,
    REGISTER,
    NEWS;

    private final long LOADED, FAILED;

    private RequestType()
    {
        LOADED  = strToAscii(this.name() + "_LOADED"  );
        FAILED = strToAscii(this.name() + "_FAILED"  );            
    }

    public static long strToAscii(String str)
    {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for (char c: str.toCharArray() )
       {
           sb.append( (int) c );
       }

      return Long.parseLong( sb.toString() );
   }
}
```

This works well for me, since I can now do `RequestType.LOGIN.LOADED == RequestType.REGISTER.LOADED` as I originally wanted. If anyone has any suggestions for improvement, feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 7):

After some comments from the OP, I've updated my code. The usage syntax gets ugly, and it may not work particularly well in `switch` blocks, but I believe this achieves what the OP is looking for:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        // Different services are not equal
        System.out.println(Service.REGISTER + "==" + Service.LOGIN + " :: " + Service.REGISTER.equals(Service.LOGIN));
        // Same service is equal
        System.out.println(Service.REGISTER + "==" + Service.REGISTER + " :: " + Service.REGISTER.equals(Service.REGISTER));
        // Even after changing the state
        Service tmp = Service.REGISTER;
        Service.REGISTER.setState(Service.ServiceState.State.FAILED);
        System.out.println(Service.REGISTER + "==" + tmp + " :: " + Service.REGISTER.equals(tmp));
        
        Service.REGISTER.setState(Service.ServiceState.State.LOADED);
        
        // Different service, same state is not equal
        System.out.println(Service.REGISTER + "." + Service.REGISTER.state + "==" + Service.LOGIN + "." + Service.LOGIN.state + " :: " + Service.REGISTER.state.equals(Service.LOGIN.state));
        
        // Same service, same state is equal (even when changing state around)
        Service.ServiceState.State temp = Service.REGISTER.getState();
        Service.REGISTER.setState(Service.ServiceState.State.LOADED);
        System.out.println(Service.REGISTER + "." + Service.REGISTER.state + "==" + tmp + "." + temp + " :: " + temp.equals(Service.REGISTER.getState()));
        
        // Same service, different state is not equal
        Service.REGISTER.setState(Service.ServiceState.State.FAILED);
        System.out.println(Service.REGISTER + "." + Service.REGISTER.state + "==" + tmp + "." + temp + " :: " + temp.equals(Service.REGISTER.getState()));
        
        // Both service and state can be used as map keys
        Map<Service, String> map = new HashMap<Service, String>();
        Map<Service.ServiceState.State, String> map2 = new HashMap<Service.ServiceState.State, String>();
    }
}

enum Service
{
    REGISTER(),
    LOGIN(),
    NEWS(),
    FAQ();

    public ServiceState state;

    Service()
    {
        this.state = new ServiceState();
    }
    
    public void setState(ServiceState.State s)
    {
        state.state = s;
    }
    
    public ServiceState.State getState() { return state.state; }

    public static class ServiceState
    {
        public enum State
        {
            LOADED,
            FAILED
        }
        
        public State state = State.LOADED;
        
        public ServiceState(){}
        
        public String toString() { return state.toString(); }
        
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return state.hashCode();
        }
        
        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            return state.equals(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
REGISTER==LOGIN :: false
REGISTER==REGISTER :: true
REGISTER==REGISTER :: true
REGISTER.LOADED==LOGIN.LOADED :: false
REGISTER.LOADED==REGISTER.LOADED :: true
REGISTER.FAILED==REGISTER.LOADED :: false
```

---

### Original Answer:

Not quite possible with the syntax you want, but Java enums are basically just classes by another name. (In fact, once compiled, they *are* classes which extend `java.lang.Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`)

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Service a = Service.REGISTER;
        a.state = Service.ServiceState.LOADED;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

enum Service
{
    REGISTER(),
    LOGIN(),
    NEWS(),
    FAQ();
    
    public ServiceState state;
    
    Service()
    {
        this.state = ServiceState.LOADED;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + "." + state.toString();
    }
    
    public enum ServiceState
    {
        LOADED,
        FAILED
    }
}
```

Output:

> REGISTER.LOADED

Comment: there's just one problem with this, i can't compare `Login.LOADED` to `Register.LOADED` and so on. I need the states to be the same type for all enums, so I can store them all in the same hashmap.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: You're wrong. With this design, the states are the same for all enums.

Comment: @AaronDigulla What about if I wanted to compare `Register.LOADED` to `Login.LOADED`, will I get different values?

Comment: @ClickUpvote, Try it? `System.out.println(Service.REGISTER.state == Service.LOGIN.state);` produces `true` (assuming you haven't changed the value of `state` on either).

Comment: @BrianS Then that doesn't solve my problem, I need the state for each service type to be unique, otherwise all my listeners for `Register.LOADED, Login.LOADED, FAQ.LOADED` etc will be fired anytime any service's status is set to `LOADED`

Comment: @ClickUpvote, Updated code, see if that satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create several enums. One lists the services:

```
enum Service {
    REGISTER, LOGIN, NEWS, FAQ;
}
```

the next one lists all states:

```
enum State { LOADED, FAILED }
```

Now you can either have a class which takes a service and a state in the constructor and which overrides equals() and hashCode() to distinguish them:

```
new ServiceState(REGISTER, LOADED)
```

or you create another enum which list valid combinations:

```
enum ServiceState {
    REGISTER_LOADED(REGISTER, LOADED), ...
}
```

but this enum will be very big and the amount to type will soon become very big (if you add one value to the other enums, you need to add N enums to `ServiceState`)

Comment: I would rather have public strings on every service which are instantiated to `this.name() + "_Loaded"` etc, if there isn't any other solution/

Comment: What's wrong with the `ServiceState` class instead of an enum?

Answer (score 1):

Just turn the "external" enum into a class and fill it with "internal" enums:

```
public class Service {
    public enum REGISTER {
        CANCELLED
    }

    // ...

    public enum LOGIN {
        LOADED
    }
}
```

or nest it as `public static` into the handler class, if it is the case.

Comment: will I be able to store `Register, Login` etc in the same hashmap if I do this? What about storing `Register.LOADED` and `Login.LOADED` in the same hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be

```
enum Service {
  REGISTER, LOGIN, NEWS, FAQ;

  public final class State {
    final ServiceState state;
    private State(ServiceState st) {
      state=st;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return Service.this+"."+state;
    }
  }
  final EnumMap<ServiceState, State> map=new EnumMap<>(ServiceState.class);
  Service() {
    for(ServiceState s:ServiceState.values()) map.put(s,new State(s));
  }
  public State state(ServiceState s) { return map.get(s); }
}
enum ServiceState { LOADED, FAILED }
```

This has the appeal of automatically adapting to changes to the possible `ServiceState`s but the code for using them is a bit odd:

```
Service.State ss=Service.LOGIN.state(ServiceState.LOADED); // LOGIN.LOADED
```

---

An alternative would be:

```
enum Service {
  REGISTER, LOGIN, NEWS, FAQ;

  public final class State {
    final ServiceState state;
    private State(ServiceState st) {
      state=st;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return Service.this+"."+state;
    }
  }
  public final State LOADED=new State(ServiceState.LOADED);
  public final State FAILED=new State(ServiceState.FAILED);
}
enum ServiceState { LOADED, FAILED }
```

which requires updating the fields manually when you change the possible `ServiceState`s but it has a more appealing syntax when using them:

```
Service.State ss=Service.LOGIN.LOADED;
```

You could also replace the `ServiceState` `enum` by the `String`s `"LOADED"`, `"FAILED"`, etc. so you don’t need to keep the `enum` and the fields inside `Service` in sync.

---

Note that both solutions rely on the fact that the constructor of `Service.State` is `private` so only the canonical instances created whithin the `enum` exist. So you don’t need to override `equals` nor `hashCode`. If you decide to make the class `Serializable` you should also add a `readResolve` method which returns the canonical representation for de-serialized instances.